# Euler characteristic for non-convex polyhedra.

Tags: general-topology, surfaces

I read a little introductory book to topology. 
It basically said that for any two-dimensional manifold (well maybe just the closed ones, as I think about it) its topology can be unambiguously defined by the Euler's characteristic and orientability.

Consequently it is very nice that any convex polyhedron has its Euler characteristic $\chi=2$ which means that the global topology is the same as for the sphere.

What about the examples below? In fact $\chi>2$ which occurs in these cases do not correspond to any global topologies I know.

[image: non-convex]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a space made up of triangles (a 2 dimensional simplicial complex, if you will, although this generalizes to higher dimensions as well) the Euler characteristic is just #vertices - #edges + #triangles.  The main theorem is that this number is only dependent on the underlying topological space (up to homotopy) and not on how you go about triangulating it, this is a corollary of the fact that simplicial and singular homology theories agree.  In both of these examples the underlying space is homotopy equivalent to two spheres connected at a point, so as expected they have the same Euler characteristic (3).

Comment: Addition: the construction of connecting spaces at a point is called “wedge sum”.

Comment: I know this is a old question, but would not the first object (left) be like two sphere connecting on a line. This line should become a great circle correct? So what is that construction called?